# What plugins do you commonly install on a fresh WordPress install?

Tags: plugins, installation

I'm looking at finding out what plugins others install most of the time on a fresh WordPress install; the plugins that add value to pretty much any website that is running WordPress.

My list of commonly installed plugins on a fresh WP install, in no particular order:

- [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) - Use whenever I need a contact form on the site
- [Page.ly MultiEdit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagely-multiedit/) - Use whenever I need multiple editable regions
- [Login LockDown](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/login-lockdown/) - Always use on public facing website. Helps prevent account brute forcing.
- [Register Plus Redux](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/register-plus-redux/) Use whenever the site allows member signup.
- [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) Use whenever the site will be displaying pages upon pages of posts.

Please answer with your commonly used installed plugins on a fresh WP install.

Answer (score 3):

These are my common plugins that I always install on all my blogs:

- [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) - Fighting with spam. I use only this plugin and it does the job very well
- [Auto Post Thumbnail](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/04/19/wordpress-plugin-automatic-post-thumbnail/) - I'm lazy with setting the featured image. This plugin will auto take the 1st image in post content and set it as the featured image.
- [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/) - Very powerful and easy to customize contact plugin.
- [SEO Smart Links](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wordpress-plugins/seo-smart-links) - Do some cool SEO things for links and images
- [Smart Archives Reloaded](http://scribu.net/wordpress/smart-archives-reloaded) - It's designed for archive page, but we can also use it for sitemap page
- [Yoast SEO Plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) - I used AIO SEO Plugin before, but I decided to switch to Yoast's plugin as it has good feature of recommendation while editing posts.
- [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) - it's the best cache plugin for me, it does some jobs in optimization, also
- [Widget Logic](http://freakytrigger.co.uk/wordpress-setup/) - Instead of hard code into theme files, I use this for controlling my widgets
- [WP-Optimize](http://www.ruhanirabin.com/wp-optimize/) - Do some optimizations such as: delete spams, post revisions, optimize tables
- [WP-PostViews](http://lesterchan.net/portfolio/programming/php/) - For simple stats like popular posts. It's lightweight, works with cache, and has nice widget
- [WPtouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) - I found this's the best plugin for mobile

Answer (score 2):

- [Add From Server](http://dd32.id.au/wordpress-plugins/add-from-server/) - allows you to upload files using FTP and then add them to galleries in wordpress
- [BackupWordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backupwordpress/) - I have had problems with backing up certain parts of the site, but still use this as it's the simplest. Getting better over time.
- Exclude Pages from Navigation - no explanation needed.
- [Invisible Defender](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/invisible-defender/) - this is a great anti-spam plugin, unfortunately it is discontinued but still works (perhaps someone wants to take the baton on this one?)
- [WP Google Fonts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-google-fonts/) - mandatory
- [WP Maintenance Mode](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/) - could never get the countdown clock working though :(

Answer (score 2):

- [Germanix URL](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) – Creates proper permalinks and filenames.*
- [Google (XML) Sitemaps](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/) – Well … what the name says.
- [Relevanssi](http://www.relevanssi.com/) – Enhances the internal search engine.
- [Subscribe To "Double-Opt-In" Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-double-opt-in-comments/) – has a speaking name too.
- [Magic Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-widgets/) – Enables widgets in `wp_header` and `wp_footer`.*
- [WordPress Database Backup](http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-db-backup/) – Daily backup.
- [Prevent Title Widows](https://github.com/toscho/Prevent-Title-Widows) – Adds a no break space between the last two words of the title.*
- [WordPress Shortcodes](https://github.com/toscho/WordPress-Shortcodes) – Shortcodes for tables etc.*
- [Last Edits Dashboard Widget](https://github.com/toscho/Last-Edits.-WordPress-Dashboard-Widget) – Table of last activities.*
- [Disable Wptexturize](https://gist.github.com/982554) – De facto a performance boost. :)*

* Written by me.

Answer (score 1):

- [Block Bad Behavior](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bad-behavior/)
- [Google XML Sitemaps](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/)
- [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) (used to use Dagon Design Form Mailer).

edit:forgot Google XML Sitemaps

Answer (score 1):

- A privately developed XML Sitemap and image XML Sitemap plugin
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- A somewhat modified version of Simple Local Avatars
- WP Smush.it

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with clients that have a support contract for updates and care I always use these plugins on a fresh install:

- [WordPress File Monitor Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-file-monitor-plus/) - Written by me, monitors your WP install for file changes
- [Update Notifier](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/update-notifier/) - I'm in the process of writing a better version, but send email alerts when WP core, themes and plugins have available updates.

EDIT: I've finished making a better Update Notifier

- [WP Updates Notifier](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-updates-notifier/)